# PyQt : QComboBox of checkable items : checkbox not displayed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am trying to make a `QComboBox` with checkable items. I created a custom Model, which my `QComboBox` object uses (via the `setModel()` method).

I tried using the solution presented in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8423904

Here is my custom model :

```
class FilterModel(QStandardItemModel):

    def __init__(self, filter_list, parent=None):
        super(FilterModel, self).__init__(parent)

        for index, filter in enumerate(filter_list):
            item = QStandardItem(filter)
            item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            item.setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)

            self.setItem(index, 0, item)
```

I pass the items as a list in the constructor when I instantiate my model.

However, my items are nor selectable, nor checkable (the checkbox isn't even displayed).

Comment: Yes, as said in my question, that's the answer I used to implement this. I copy/pasted his code, transformed it from C++ to Python, but here I am, it does not work (items are nor selectable, nor checkable).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the checkbox doesn't show but for the item to be selectable you'll also need to include the `Qt.ItemIsSelectable` flag.

In any case, why don't you try the `QStandardItem.setCheckable` method? Something like this:

```
class FilterModel(QStandardItemModel):

    def __init__(self, filter_list, parent=None):
        super(FilterModel, self).__init__(parent)

        for index, filter in enumerate(filter_list):
            item = QStandardItem(filter)
            item.setSelectable(True)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            self.setItem(index, 0, item)
```