# How to set display text for ComboBox (checkable) in Qt

Tags: qt, checkbox, combobox

I follow these to create checkable combobox

[ComboBox of CheckBoxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422760/combobox-of-checkboxes)

http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/ModelView/ComboBoxOfCheckBoxes

However when I do a this->Model->clear() then add items, the combobox text (the text combobox displays before user clicking anything) goes blank. The items will still show and are checkable when click on the combobox. I suspect the clear() remove the header and causes this, however I try setHorizontalHeaderLabels etc but I still can't set the combobox text. What am I missing?

Comment: I can't post more image as I'm restricted to post more than 2 links... Here are the image of normal combobox and combobox after clear (display text gone)...


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zf0u.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcgk4.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the ComboBox's selected index after you add items. Like:

```
ui->combobox->setCurrentIndex(0);
```

Because it could be that after you clear the ComboBox, its display index may have gone to -1 and stayed there even if  you add items.

Comment: Perfect. setCurrentIndex fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Figured out how to mark an answer as the solution. Done it.