# CheckBox not visible inside ComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qcombobox, qcheckbox

I need my combobox items to be checkable by user so they can select multiple items. I've seen some solution on stackoverflow. I applied it to my code. It did something, but checkbox aren't visible yet and I'm not yet able to select any item.

My code is as follows

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import * 

udims = [here goes some items]
cmb = QComboBox()
model = QStandardItemModel(len(udims), 1)
for i, udim in enumerate(udims):
    item = QStandardItem(udim)
    item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    item.setData(Qt.Checked | Qt.CheckStateRole)
    model.setItem(i, 0, item)

cmb.setModel(model)
```

Comment: This sample code is not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is annoying as it is quite easy (especially in Python) to make one: Please, fix assignment of `udims` (e.g. `udims = ["here", "goes", "some", "items"]`); fix `model = QStandardItemModel(len(items), 1)` (e.g. `model = QStandardItemModel(len(udims), 1)`); fix `item = QStandarItem(udim)` (typo); add an instance of `QApplication()`. I did all this (locally) in PyQt5 and got it running. Btw. I didn't see checkboxes in my PyQt5 "port" as well.

Comment: The behavior you describe (no checkboxes, no hover selection) I've seen on my side as well (cygwin, python3, PyQt5). Have a look at [SO: ComboBox of CheckBoxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20118475/7478597). May be, you have to use the item delegate trick to make them visible. Btw. I believe there is another typo in `item.setData(Qt.Checked | Qt.CheckStateRole)`: Shouldn't it be `item.setData(Qt.Checked, Qt.CheckStateRole)` (i.e. **`,`** instead of **`|`**)?

Comment: ItemDelegate trick solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by creating a subclass of QItemDelegate for the checkbox, then plugging that into the item delegate for the combobox.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class CheckBoxDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckBoxDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(parent, op, idx):
        self.editor = QCheckBox(parent)


udims = ['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004']
cmb = QComboBox()
delegate = CheckBoxDelegate()
cmb.setItemDelegate(delegate)
model = QStandardItemModel(len(udims), 1)
for i, udim in enumerate(udims):
    item = QStandardItem(udim)
    item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    item.setData(Qt.Checked | Qt.CheckStateRole)
    model.setItem(i, 0, item)

cmb.setModel(model)
```