# How to convert a QComboBox to contain checkboxes instead of a simple dropdown list?

Tags: python, qt, maya, qcombobox

Does anyone know how to make a dropdown checkbox in Qt? I am using Maya.
so far I have:

```
    self.transform_dropdown = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    self.transform_dropdown.addItem("Freeze transform")
    self.transform_dropdown.addItem("Freeze rotation")
    self.transform_dropdown.addItem("Freeze scale")
```

I cant find any information on how to convert these into checkboxes and query their state.

Comment: Noop, that is not the way to go. Combo box are for selecting one option out of multiple. So you will need to create multiple checkboxes outside the combobox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ComboBox of CheckBoxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422760/combobox-of-checkboxes)

Comment: are you looking for some behaviour as  menu item ?